# JavaScript forEach implementation

Tags: javascript

I found a code snippet for a `forEach` function on a tutorial website, and everything makes good sense to me except for the line that checks if `i` is in the array:

```
    if (i in this) {
```

Why bother if we already have a for loop that has a stop condition?

```
if (!Array.prototype.forEach) {
Array.prototype.forEach = function(fun /*, thisp*/) {
    var len = this.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun != "function") {
        throw new TypeError();
    }

    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (i in this) {
            fun.call(thisp, this[i], i, this);
        }
    }
};
}
```

Comment: thanks everyone, very fast response time :)

Comment: That's Stack Overflow's specialty :D

Comment: Here is an exhaustive analysis of this code snippet: http://javascript.about.com/od/hintsandtips/a/foreach.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Two reasons:

### 1. Mutation by the callback

Calling `fun` might change the array, since `fun` is entirely user-defined. So you need to check again.

Example:

```
array.forEach(function (el, i) { delete array[i + 1]; });
```

### 2. Sparse arrays

The other issue is that there can be sparse arrays: e.g.

```
3 in ["a", "b", "c", , "e", "f"] === false
// even though
3 in ["a", "b", "c", undefined, "e", "f"] === true
```

In those cases you don't want to call `fun` for that index/element, since there is nothing at that index.

```
["a", "b", "c", , "e", "f"].forEach(function (el, i) {
    console.log(el + " at " + i);
});
// => "a at 0" "b at 1" "c at 2" "e at 4" "f at 5"
```

Comment: Maybe a more typical way of creating a sparse array: `var a = []; a[3] == "d";`.

Answer (score 3):

Because an array can have holes, and therefore you can iterate over the length and not all values will exist.

```
x = new Array()
[]

x[0] = "zero"
"zero"

x[5] = "five"
"five"

x
["zero", undefined × 4, "five"]

3 in x
false

x.length
6

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { console.log(i, i in x, x[i])}
0 true "zero"
1 false undefined
2 false undefined
3 false undefined
4 false undefined
5 true "five"
```

Comment: This really has very little to do with the specific situation in question. No -1, but read the question a bit more carefully.

Comment: @Domenic - You're right I was too hasty. I have edited my answer to address the actual qu!

Comment: hmm one discrepancy I see is that Domenic has (x in arr) evaluate to true when the value at x is undefined, and you seem to have it evaluate to false. SHould it only be false when the value is absent completely?

Comment: Both `null` and `undefined` are actually values in JavaScript (you can assign them, as he did in his example). The output in my answer come from the Chrome JavaScript tools. Look at this: `["a", undefined , "f"] ->
["a", undefined, "f"]
["a", , "f"] ->
["a", undefined × 1, "f"]`. Notice the difference in how they are printed. I think it's just down to how the console deals with printing sparse holes.